# Tomcat server - restart need when method signature changes

Tags: java

When I change method signature of Controller class, eclipse ask if server need to be restarted. Why do we need to restart server in this case for change to be reflected? For any other changes in class file NO restart is needed but the changes done are reflected.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322996/what-code-changes-are-automatically-reflected-in-eclipse-in-debug-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You are using a mechanism called *Hot Swap* which allows you to change method body without restarting the JVM. Unfortunately this is the only supported mechanism. [Check out](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/) [jrebel](/questions/tagged/jrebel) (commercial) which supports many other refactorings/changes.